# PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the following error and I am unable to correct it

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /home1/jkendall/public_html/princeave.com/bo/before_care_finalize_billing.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /home1/jkendall/public_html/princeave.com/bo/before_care_finalize_billing.php(60): PDO->rollBack() #1 {main} thrown in /home1/jkendall/public_html/princeave.com/bo/before_care_finalize_billing.php on line 60

The code that is causing this is below.  I have removed the insert statement and entered an echo statement and ran the code to verify that the data is getting passed and it is.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['set']) && isset($_POST['set']) !="") {
    $size = count($_POST['charge_id']);
    $i = 0; 
    while ($i < $size) {
        $usid=$_SESSION['uid'];
        $approval_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $bill_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $transaction_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $customer_ID = $_POST['customer_ID'][$i];
        $student_ID = $_POST['student_ID'][$i];
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'][$i];
        $account = $_POST['account'][$i];
        $description = $_POST['description'][$i];
        $bill_amount = $_POST['bill_amount'][$i];
        echo $usid." Approval ".$approval_date." Bill ".$bill_date." Transaction ".$transaction_date." ".$customer_ID." ".$student_ID." ".$full_name." ".$account." ".$description." ".$bill_amount."<br> ";
        try{
            $stmta[$i] = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bo_transactions(transaction_date, customer_ID, student_ID, full_name, account_num, description, bill_amount, bill_date, user_id, approval_date) VALUES (:transaction_date, :customer_ID, :student_ID, :full_name, :account, :description, :charge, :bill_date, :usid, :approval_date)");
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':usid',$usid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':approval_date',$approval_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':bill_date',$bill_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':transaction_date',$transaction_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':customer_ID',$customer_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':student_ID',$student_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':full_name',$full_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':account',$account,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':bill_amount',$bill_amount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->execute();
            //exit();
        }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $db->rollBack();
                echo $e->getMessage();
                //exit();
            }
        ++$i;
    }
    header(sprintf('Location: before_care_select_students.php'));
}
```

Comment: You need to start a transaction to be able to rollback, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php.

Comment: Please do something more useful than printing out the error, this is of very little use to the end user and usually will mean they don't view your system as something well written.  Especially don't call something like `die` as in the answer below - also not user friendly.

Comment: @NigelRen: I've added an edit to address that. My intent was more of a general debugging step as opposed to something that would get used anywhere other than a basic example/development test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code never starts a transaction. In order to rollback, you need to first create a transaction, otherwise it's just going to insert it. Below is your code where I've added both a `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` function.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['set']) && isset($_POST['set']) !="") {
    $size = count($_POST['charge_id']);
    $i = 0; 

    $db->beginTransaction();
    while ($i < $size) {
        $usid=$_SESSION['uid'];
        $approval_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $bill_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $transaction_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $customer_ID = $_POST['customer_ID'][$i];
        $student_ID = $_POST['student_ID'][$i];
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'][$i];
        $account = $_POST['account'][$i];
        $description = $_POST['description'][$i];
        $bill_amount = $_POST['bill_amount'][$i];
        echo $usid." Approval ".$approval_date." Bill ".$bill_date." Transaction ".$transaction_date." ".$customer_ID." ".$student_ID." ".$full_name." ".$account." ".$description." ".$bill_amount."<br> ";

        try{
            $stmta[$i] = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bo_transactions(transaction_date, customer_ID, student_ID, full_name, account_num, description, bill_amount, bill_date, user_id, approval_date) VALUES (:transaction_date, :customer_ID, :student_ID, :full_name, :account, :description, :charge, :bill_date, :usid, :approval_date)");
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':usid',$usid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':approval_date',$approval_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':bill_date',$bill_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':transaction_date',$transaction_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':customer_ID',$customer_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':student_ID',$student_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':full_name',$full_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':account',$account,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->bindParam(':bill_amount',$bill_amount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmta[$i]->execute();
            //exit();
        }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $db->rollBack();
                echo $e->getMessage();
                die("Bad insert");
            }
        ++$i;
    }

    $db->commit();
    header(sprintf('Location: before_care_select_students.php'));
}
```

Notes:

1. Putting the transaction commands around your while loop insures that your database is only changed if all the records are successfully submitted.
2. As someone else pointed out, putting `exit()` or `die()` in production code is generally a bad idea. It seemed that you had included `exit()` as a part of your debugging work, and wanted to put something in there that was slightly more helpful to that end.

Comment: Thank you. For my learning, I have other statements that do work without the begintranscation and commit statements.  What is that?

Comment: @user3395907: Hard to say without seeing some of the code myself. But using transactions is completely optional. In fact, the default is to not use transactions. So, if you didn't included a `rollBack()`, they would work without issue.

Comment: If that doesn't seem like the issue, you may want to ask a second question and reference this one. I'd be happy to take a look if you did so :)